# Import Tool Tips from Webpage into Google Sheets

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets

I am trying to pull data from a gaming website into a google sheets. I tried using importxml looking for li, list items and it's not bringing in. Any of the tool tips.

I'm trying to pull from this webpage: https://mobilelegends.midorfeed.net/en/hero/Ruby-29

There are some move information if you hover over the 4 Icons to the right of the character picture and name. This has the move statistics. I want to pull all that information into the google sheet.

I also want to pull in the recommend items stats information that's midway through the page, but is also in the tooltips. So I hope this will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal as follows.

- Your question has 2 questions.

  > 1. There are some move information if you hover over the 4 Icons to the right of the character picture and name. This has the move statistics. I want to pull all that information into the google sheet.

  > 2. I also want to pull in the recommend items stats information that's midway through the page, but is also in the tooltips.
- You want to achieve this using `IMPORTXML` in Google Spreadsheet.

Unfortunately, from `I tried using importxml looking for li, list items and it's not bringing in.`, I couldn't understand about your formulas. So I proposed the following sample formulas.

#### Answer for question 1:

Please put the URL of `https://mobilelegends.midorfeed.net/en/hero/Ruby-29` to the cell "A1".

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//li/@title")
```

Result:

[image]

#### Answer for question 2:

Please put the URL of `https://mobilelegends.midorfeed.net/en/hero/Ruby-29` to the cell "A1".

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//div[@class='container']/@title")
```

Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- From your question, I couldn't understand about the result you expected. So above proposed formulas directly return the values for your question. Please be careful this.
- When you changed the URL, above formulas might not be able to be used. So please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)